# Achievement information retrieving

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services, achievements

I want to show a button in my game with the Totalnumber of increments.

```
theButton.setText(Integer.toString(game.appObj.firedIncrements(achString)));
```

Following function returns the value succesfully.

```
//returns -1 or the number of steps;
public int  firedIncrements(String achStringId)  {


    boolean fullLoad = false;  // set to 'true' to reload all achievements (ignoring cache)
    long waitTime = 20;    // seconds to wait for achievements to load before timing out
    // load achievements
    int steps=-1;
    PendingResult p = Games.Achievements.load( mGoogleApiClient, fullLoad );
    Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult r = (Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult)p.await( waitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    int status = r.getStatus().getStatusCode();
    if ( status != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK )  {
        r.release();
        return -1;           // Error Occurred
    }

    // process the loaded achievements
    AchievementBuffer buf = r.getAchievements();
    int bufSize = buf.getCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++ )  {
        Achievement ach = buf.get( i );

        // here you now have access to the achievement's data
        if(achStringId==ach.getAchievementId())
        {
            steps = ach.getCurrentSteps();
        }
        //String id = ach.getAchievementId();  // the achievement ID string

         steps = ach.getCurrentSteps();  // current incremental steps
    }
    buf.release();
    r.release();
    return steps;
}
```

But it needs a wait state.
Can I do this without this wait state.
To be more specific, i need to access the "Achievement details" from the apiClient object directly.
Is it possible for me  without  storing them locally in seperate data tables or preferences.?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Would it not be possible to load the data you need before creating the button? Possibly load the information during a loading screen!?

Comment: thanks..nice idea, it is possible, but i want to know how to do it momentarily from mGoogleApiClient , since i want to get the current increment state of the achievements, as the game progresses.

Comment: I would still suggest to load the initial state during a loading screen, and then display the text you get in the button - during the game, as the state changes, show the _old_ text to the user, until the next text is returned. Maybe you could _fade_ the button out, until the text is returned by the API call?